# What would be considered the root directory to a third party javascript in Django

Tags: django

When using Send Pulse they instruct you place a javascript in the head of your template. This javascript then refers to 2 other scripts that they instruct you to place in the root of you web site. Where can these be placed so that their javascript will automatically find them in the "web root"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that the service is expecting to find the scripts directly under `/`, eg `mywebsite.com/script1.js`. But in Django static files are usually under `/static` or the equivalent. There is nowhere you can just "place" them to get them to appear at the right URL.

But that doesn't mean you can't do it. The best thing to do would be to add an explicit mapping in your web server (nginx or Apache) for those scripts. For example, in nginx:

```
location /script1.js { alias /path/to/staticdir/script1.js; }
```

Comment: Thank You! I modified my nginx config file and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of possible options. In no particular order:

- [@daniel-roseman's suggestion of using a rewrite/alias configured in your webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879785/844976)
- Modify the javascript that you're going to place in the head of your page, so that it loads the scripts from your `/static` folder (followed by placing those scripts there, of course)
- Use an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) to return these script(s) from a view function, and then map the target URLs (like mywebsite.com/script1.js) to the view.

This might look like:

```
# urls.py - assuming >= Django 2.0
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    # place script1.js into your static folder, then reference its location within the static folder
    path('script1.js', views.javascript_loader, {'script_path': 'script1.js'}),
]

# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
import os

def javascript_loader(request, script_path):
    # note: you should cache this content for the use case you've described, just 
    # consider this an illustration of how to load/return content from a static 
    # file using a view. 
    full_script_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, script_path)

    with open(full_script_path, 'r') as f:
        javascript_contents = f.read()

    return HttpResponse(javascript_contents, mimetype="text/javascript")
```

Again, not sure which solution would be best for your needs, but *one* of those should get you the result you need.